# How to fix error 414 uri too long when calling api for upload image to server for mobilefirst 8

Tags: ionic-framework, http-post, ibm-mobilefirst

i update the app from mfp 7.1 to 8. For mfp 7, the feature for uploading the image is working fine but for mfp 8 try to call same method the server throw uri too long.The server dont have any changes, only the app side

but if i sent without Photo which is base64 the api return success.The source code for camera function is exactly the same for both version mfp7.1 and 8

```
mfp7.1 server request(Working)

var locale  =   localStorageService.get('locale');
var rptList =   localStorageService.get('rptList');
var channel =   localStorageService.get('rptChannel');
var os      =   localStorageService.get('rptOs');
var type    =   localStorageService.get('rptOption');
var station =    
localStorageService.get('mrReportHistoryDetailStation');
var desc    =    
localStorageService.get('mrReportHistoryDetailDesc');
var loc     =   localStorageService.get('rptLoc');
var accNo   =   localStorageService.get('rptAccNo');
var issueType   =   localStorageService.get('rptIssueType');
var photo   =   localStorageService.get('rptPhoto');    

console.log(rptList);
console.log('Make Report adapter');
var deferred = $q.defer();
var invocationData = {
    adapter : "Report",
    procedure : "makeReport",
    parameters : [{
      LOCALE:locale,
      CHANNEL:channel,
      CLIENT_OS:os,
      TYPE:type,
      ISSUE_TYPE:issueType,
      STATION:(type === 'GENERAL_INQUIRY')?"" : station,
      CATEGORY:(type === 'GENERAL_INQUIRY')?station : "",
      DESCRIPTION:desc,
      LOCATION:loc,
      CONTRACT_ACC_NO:accNo,
      PHOTOS:photo
    }]
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(invocationData));
var options = {
    onSuccess : $.proxy(function (result){
      deferred.resolve(result.invocationResult);
    }, this),
    onFailure : $.proxy(function (res){
      deferred.reject(res);
    }, this)
};



 mfp8 (Not Working)


 var locale = localStorageService.get('locale');
  var rptList = localStorageService.get('rptList');
  var channel = localStorageService.get('rptChannel');
  var os = localStorageService.get('rptOs');
  var type = localStorageService.get('rptOption');
  var station = 
  localStorageService.get('mrReportHistoryDetailStation');
  var desc = localStorageService.get('mrReportHistoryDetailDesc');
  var loc = localStorageService.get('rptLoc');
  var accNo = localStorageService.get('rptAccNo');
  var issueType = localStorageService.get('rptIssueType');
  var photo = localStorageService.get('rptPhoto');


  console.log(rptList);
  console.log('Make Report adapter');
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  var invocationData = {
    LOCALE: locale,
    CHANNEL: channel,
    CLIENT_OS: os,
    TYPE: type,
    ISSUE_TYPE: issueType,
    STATION: type === 'GENERAL_INQUIRY' ? '' : station,
    CATEGORY: type === 'GENERAL_INQUIRY' ? station : '',
    DESCRIPTION: desc,
    LOCATION: loc,
    CONTRACT_ACC_NO: accNo,
    PHOTOS: photo
  };

  var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest(
    '/adapters/Report/makeReport',
    WLResourceRequest.POST
  );
  alert('resource');
  console.log(resourceRequest);
  resourceRequest.setQueryParameter('params', [invocationData]);
  resourceRequest.send().then(
    response => {
      alert('return');
      this.content = response.responseJSON;
      console.log(
        'Report make report====>>>' + JSON.stringify(this.content)
      );
      deferred.resolve(this.content);
      alert('Success');
    },
    function(error) {
      console.log('error message' + JSON.stringify(error));
      deferred.reject(error);
    }
  );
```

it return success for mfp7.1 code but for mfp 8 it return error 414 uri is too long. but if without photo the api return success.
Photo is base64Image

Comment: did you try using bodyParams instead of `setQueryParameter`?

Comment: Can u explain about bodyParams, i cannot find anywhere on documentation.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using FormParams instead of QueryParams, as QueryParams will be passed in the URL and it has some limitation to number of characters. Instead you can pass your json as FormParam,

```
var request = WLResourceRequest(url, method, options);
request.sendFormParameters(json).then(
    function(response) {
        // success flow
    },
    function(error) {
        // fail flow
    }
);
```

For further reference, visit below link and see methods for `WLResourceRequest`.

http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/api/client-side-api/javascript/client/

Comment: Thanks for example. Do i need to change anything on server configuration or in adapter side. Cause using get method is working but without base 64image. The problem i face right now is want to send the image to back end. im using same api link as mfp 7.1. Please help me on this, already stuck for days

Comment: is it a java adapter or javascript adapter?